# reloadData Issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, reloaddata

I am attempting to reload the data from my tableView. When calling it from it's own void, it doesn't work and nothing happens. However, when looking around it works when I delete a cell. I am thinking it has something to do with my INIT. Can you help me solve it? Thanks.

Below is my code!

```
- (id) init {

//NSLog(@"%@", theUserID);
// Set up database connection
NSString *myDBTwo = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"flashpics.db"];
databaseTwo = [[Sqlite alloc] init];
[databaseTwo open:myDBTwo];

//Initialize the array.
listOfItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[listOfItems addObject:@"hi!"];

// Add to array to display in the tableView
NSArray *listOfItemsTwo = [databaseTwo executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM albums"];   
for (NSDictionary *rowone in listOfItemsTwo) {
    NSString *getName = [rowone valueForKey:@"name"];
    if (getName != NULL) {
        [listOfItems addObject:getName];
        [getName release];
    }
}

//[database release];

return self;
}
```

Here's my void:

```
- (void)refreshTableView {
[(UITableView *)self.view reloadData];
//[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does "When calling it from it's own void" mean? which method are you talking about? Also in your refreshTableView method, you can just do [self.tableView reloadData]. Presuming this method is in a UItableViewController based class.

Comment: Calling my own void is that it's in the same class. I did [self.tableView reloadData]; and nothing occurs. But being putting it in my `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`, it works. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are over-releasing `getName`, so I would expect this to crash. But if nothing is happening when `-refreshTableView` is called, then I would expect that `self.view` is `nil`. You should verify the following:

- `refreshTableView` is actually called
- `self.view` is not `nil` at the point that it is used
- `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, and returns a properly configured cell when requested

Comment: refreshTableView IS called. What do you mean it's nil? It's not being shown? And tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath IS NOT being called.

Comment: Log the value of `self.view` in `refreshTableView`. Make sure that it's actually set to something. The most common cause of "nothing happens" is that you forgot to wire something in IB. Given your other comments, you also might be making calls prior to `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Here's what I get for the self.view in the refreshTableView `<UITableView: 0x88f2a00; frame = (0 20; 320 460); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x819bec0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>`

Comment: Just checked. tableView IS connected to the UITableView in interface builder.

Comment: So continue walking through the table view datasource methods. After calling [self.view reloadData], you should expect `numberOfRowsInTableView:` to be called. After that, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You walk through until you find the piece that doesn't get called or is nil.

Comment: The NSLog shows that it is being called from the refreshTableView in both `numberOfRowsInTableView:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. In a NSLog in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, I echoed all the text in the cells, but the new submitting wasn't there. The weird part was that I did yet another NSLog and it showed the array which had the new field.

Comment: After some looking into it called the `numberOfRowsInTableView:` correctly with the updated number. Then it called the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and I did a NSLog on the array and it was all there (including the new stuff). But then it called `numberOfRowsInTableView:` again and reverted the count back to what it was (and the array didn't include the new data inserted).

Comment: `numberOfRowsInTableView:` is your responsibility. It's up to you to return the correct number of rows, and to manage any insertions into the array. The tableview has no idea how you store your data. It just asks "how many rows are there?" Then it asks "What's cell is in row 0?" Insertions are done by the tableview telling you "hey, the user wants to insert something here; you should do something about that" and then coming back and asking "so, how many rows are there now?" All issues of data are your problem, not the tableview's.